# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para validar los datos de un excel en php y antes de subirlo a la BD?

Tags: php, base-de-datos, excel, validación, phpexcel

tengo un problema el cual aún no logro resolver y agradecería muchísimo si me pueden ayudar o dar una idea de como lo puedo resolver. Les comento: Estoy elaborando un programa en el cual pueda subir un excel (tabla) a la BD la tabla contiene el ID, NOMBRE, APELLIDO, TELEFONO, CORREO, CÓDIGO POSTAL eso es algo que ya logre hacer, mi problema radica en que antes de subír mi excel a la BD quiero validar mis datos.

Este es mi código

```html
<?php 
    if(is_array($_FILES['archivoexcel']) && count($_FILES['archivoexcel'])>0){
        
        //Se llama a la libreria phpExcel
        require_once 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
        require_once 'conexion.php';

        $tmpfname = $_FILES['archivoexcel']['tmp_name'];
        //crear excel para leerlo despues
        $leerexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
        
     //Cargar Excel
     $excelobj = $leerexcel->load($tmpfname);
     
     //Cargar la hoja en la que se trabajara
     $hoja = $excelobj -> getSheet (0);
     $filas = $hoja ->getHighestRow();
    

     echo "<table id='table_detalle' class='table' style='width:100%;
     table-layout:fixed'>
        <thead>
            <tr bgcolor='black' style='color:pink'>
                <td> idContactos </td>
                <td> Nombre </td>
                <td> Apellido </td>
                <td> Telefono </td>
                <td> Correo </td>
                <td> Codigo Postal </td>
            </tr>
        </thead><tbody id='tbody_tabla_detalle'>";
        
        for($row = 2;$row<=$filas;$row++){
            $idContactos = $hoja->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
            $nombre = $hoja->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();
            $primerApellido = $hoja->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();
            $telefono = $hoja->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
            $correo = $hoja->getCell('E'.$row)->getValue();
            $codigoPostal = $hoja->getCell('F'.$row)->getValue();
            $query = "select count(*) as contador from contactos where idContactos='".$idContactos."'";
            $resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
            $respuesta = $resultado->fetch_assoc();  
            if($respuesta['contador']=='0'){ 
                if($idContactos==""){

                }else{
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td> ".$idContactos." </td>";
                    echo "<td> ".$nombre." </td>";
                    echo "<td> ".$primerApellido." </td>";
                    echo "<td> ".$telefono." </td>";
                    echo "<td> ".$correo." </td>";
                    echo "<td> ".$codigoPostal." </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            
            }
            
        }
        
        echo "</tbody></table>";
            

    }


?>
```

Comment: ¿Y qué reglas de validación te gustaría implementar? ¿Cómo has intentado implementarlas?

Comment: Por ejemplo que valide si los campos son numéricos avise que no se pueden subir caracteres, si es fecha que no suba texto, o si es un numero ya sea de teléfono o Cp no ingrese letras @DavidJP

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado?

Comment: @DavidJP intente usar ` if (ctype_alpha($nombre)) { ` pero al intentar agregar el apellido este no me funciona

Comment: Modifica tu pregunta añadiendo lo que comentas y el `INSERT` con el que irás subiendo los datos. Lo que que obtienes y lo que esperas obtener. Vamos a empezar con ejemplos sencillos...